# How can I tell MySQL to only check the latest x entries during a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a page that selects all the users in my database. There's only a thousand or two. No big deal.

However, while it's selecting that, it's also using their uid from that query to check another table with around 25,000 entries.

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM logs
WHERE time+date > {$timeNow} AND uid={$row['id']}
```

It does that **for each user entry**. As you can imagine, this gets pretty resource intensive.

The `WHERE` clause above will only apply to perhaps the last day's worth of entries, maybe 500-1000 at most. It can, however, effect more than that.

I was thinking I could set up a cronjob to export all entries that don't match the `WHERE` clause once or twice per day to another table. I know that would dramatically help and even solve the problem in a somewhat efficient manner. However, I don't really like having two tables for the same (relative) purpose.

Is there a better way I can do it? I've search around for a good while now and I can't find any, but I thought I'd ask you guys in case you've come across the same problem and found a unique method to solve it.

**EDIT** For Brendan Long:
My new query:

```
$SQL = "SELECT u.id, COUNT(l.id) " .
       "FROM users u " .
       "INNER JOIN logs l " .
       "ON l.uid = u.id " .
       "WHERE l.time+l.date > {$timeNow} " .
       "GROUP BY u.id";
```

Also, please don't bash on me for a lack of PDO. I haven't had time to convert this over yet. I know I'm a terrible person.

Comment: So the results from this query are used to select more data from another table? Why not use a where IN on all the IDs together?

Comment: @David Not sure what you mean, but each result from this query gets paired up with the relevant user to post some stats on the userpanel on my site.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) so the database can optimize it for you as one query:

```
SELECT u.uid, COUNT(l.id)
FROM Users u -- or whatever your users table is named
LEFT JOIN logs l
ON l.uid = u.uid AND l.time + l.date > $timeNow
GROUP BY u.uid
```

In English, this tells the database, "get me a list of user IDs and the number of logs associated with them, where `time + date` is after `$timeNow`". This is significantly more efficient, since you're giving the database all of the work at once, so it can figure out the optimal way to get *all* of the information, instead of grabbing one piece at a time.

### Joins

The `LEFT JOIN` tells the database to match up users with logs by looking for records where the users table and logs table have the same `uid`. The `LEFT` in `LEFT JOIN` tells the database to return a result for a user (the **left** side of the join), even if they don't have any logs associated with them (the right side of the join). If you don't want to see results where there's no logs for a user, you can do an `INNER JOIN`, which will only show results where there's a match on both sides of the join (both a user and at least one log message).

### Group By

The `GROUP BY` is necessary to group the results by user ID -- otherwise you'd just get the total number of log messages associated with *any* user, which is presumably not helpful since you could just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs`.

I'm using table aliases to make the query shorter because it's the style I've always used, but you can easily just put the full names of the tables (`logs.uid`, etc.). You may even be able to get away with no including the table names, but your database will get confused when you refer to a column that exists in multiple tables in your query, so I find it's simplest to always be explicit about which column you're talking about.

### Indexes

This new query should finish instantaneously unless you have an insanely large database. If it doesn't, take @charly's advice and try some indexes. Unfortunately, you add `l.time + l.date` before using the value, and I don't think MySQL will let you create an index on `l.time + l.date`, but you may be able to get decent results by filtering on `l.date` first (which is indexable):

```
ON l.uid = u.uid AND l.date > $timeNow AND l.time + l.date > $timeNow
```

This looks repetitive, but it gives the database more to work with, since it can:

1. Fetch results where `l.date` is after `$timeNow` **using the index**.
2. Filter that (hopefully small) set of results with `l.time + l.date > $timeNow`.

Instead of:

1. For **every record in the table**, add `l.time + l.date`.
2. Check if that result is after `$timeNow`

### PHP

To do this in PHP, you'll want to do something like:

```
$sql = // that query above
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "User " . $row[0] . " posted " . $row[1] . " times.";
}
```

Or if you need to use this in a more complicated way, fetch it all upfront:

```
$counts = array();
$sql = // that query above
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $counts[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}

// later
$user = 5; // some user we care about
echo "User " . $user . " posted " . $counts[$user] . " times.";
```

If you do it the "fetch it all upfront" way, you can also optimize a little by using the `INNER JOIN` version of the query with the knowledge that any user not in `$counts` has a count of 0.

Sorry if my syntax is wrong, but I think this shows the idea.

### Security Note

On a minor tangent: It looks like you're dropping variables directly into your query, which is [generally a bad idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are a number of [incredibly complicated solutions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), but the easiest is to just [use parametrized queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put variables directly into your SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer. Very well put together and very informative. I've been following along as you updated it and been playing with the statement. It's managed to cut down on query time by a whopping 66%. This is great. The only problem is that it's reading the same count for each and every user, and the count is wrong, at that. Any ideas?

Comment: @Rob I just made one more change to select and group by `u.uid` instead of `l.uid`. I'm not sure if this would make any practical difference. Since it's a left join I realized it was weird to group by something on the right side of the join. Can you edit your question to add the exact query you're using now and an example of the results?

Comment: Edited. As for the results, it returns 604 every time. Which doesn't even make sense, to be honest. I have no idea how it's getting 604.

Comment: @Rob Is it possible the PHP code isn't looping correctly? The only thing I see in the query that seems even possibly wrong is `COUNT(l.id)`, which may be better as `COUNT(*)`, but that only makes a different if `l.id` is nullable. Something you could try for debugging is Making it a `SELECT *` and removing the `GROUP BY`, so you can see the full result set and which rows MySQL says match the query.

Comment: To loop through results, you'll need something like `$result = mysql_query($sql); while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { /* do stuff with each row */ }`.

Comment: That's how I am doing the looping. I'll try the select. One moment.

Comment: Oh, one other thing I forgot to point out: where in this statement are we specifying which uid to look up?

Comment: @Rob This statement looks up all users who have posted in the given timeframe. So, instead of telling the database which users to look  up, the database **tells you** which users have results. If you want to limit to a particular list, you could use another join, or an [`in` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

Comment: Your problem may be that you're running this query for each user, when you actually only need to run it once and it will tell you the results for all of them.

Comment: I need it to return the count for each individual user rather than all of them combined.

Comment: Oh and you can use `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` if you only want a certain number of results (like the top 10 would be `ORDER BY COUNT(l.id) LIMIT 100`).

Comment: @Rob The result will be one row for each user where the first column is the user ID and the second column is the count, so I think it's doing what you want, you just need to fetch it differently than you are (I think). Instead of running this for every user, run it once and then walk through the results and use them however you need to (or if you plan to run other queries, run this one first and put the results in an associative array, then pull results out as you need them).

Comment: @Rob I added something to my answer showing how I'd expect this query to be used.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Looking at it now, I think the problem is that it's not returning anything for users that DON'T have a log matching the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Rob Try the `LEFT JOIN` version in my current answer. It will return results for all users, even if they don't have any matching logs.

Comment: I moved the `WHERE` clause into the `JOIN` condition in case that was causing the problem. This way it's definitely guaranteed to return one result per user. I'm not sure if the old version was guaranteed to do that with the left join. Probably not since it would get `NULL` results.

Comment: I don't know man, the latest version isn't working at all and even takes a lot longer to complete, even after moving it out of the while loop.

Comment: @Rob Make sure you have indexes on the `uid` columns. Making `l.time` and `l.date` one column (presumably a DATETIME) and then adding an index on (l.uid, l.datetime) may help significantly. Is the new query slower than checking all of the these users individually?

Comment: Making l.time and l.date a single column isn't an option in this, unfortunately, and yes. It's slower than checking them individually.

Comment: @Rob Unfortunately I'm not sure what else to say. The indexes should help, but I can't imagine why this query would be slower than doing thousands of individual queries for the same data.. It's possible this query is looking up more data that before (for all users vs some subset of users?). Like I said above, you can use `INNER JOIN` to only get users with some results, or an `IN` clause to limit to a particular group.

Comment: @Rob Oh here's something to try if you can't combine the columns: Put an index on (l.uid, l.date) and do `ON l.uid = u.uid AND l.date > {$timeNow} AND l.time + l.date > {$timeNow}`. It may be able to use the index for the `l.date > {$timeNow}` part which would dramatically effect the efficiency. Trying it with just an index on `l.date` might be worth a try too if that doesn't help. I editted a better formatted version of this into my answer.

Comment: I'll work on a bit more later tonight. Family duties at the moment. Thanks for all the help so far; I really appreciate it. I'll update you when I have a moment to look into it some more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure but maybe adding a BTREE index on the uid column. Then your query will be much more efficient as it won't scan all the logs that are not of the specified uid.

Though I'm not 100% sure